# Delphi documentations makes a difference between abort and Abort - Is it a bug in doc or is Delphi case sensitive?

Tags: delphi

This documentation page says in a **prominent** notice that there are two abort instructions in Delphi. One is called `abort` and the other is called `Abort`.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Silent_Exceptions

> Note: There is a distinction between Abort and abort. abort kills the
>   application.

Is it really Delphi case sensitive (I don't have access to Delphi until tomorrow to test it). From what I know the `Register` instruction [is the only case sensitive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Declaring_the_Register_Procedure) instruction in Delphi. And there is also a "logical" exception from that: the importing of external functions.

Comment: In Delphi, both `abort` and `Abort` raises an (silent) exception. Neither kills the application (Vcl)

Comment: Seems like a doc error. There is no difference between `abort` and `Abort`, AFAIK. And I really don't think that a "silent exception" is the proper way to break out of nested loops. I'd rather use a `goto`. <g>

Comment: Perhaps the sentence is meant to be for `C++ builder`

Comment: Difficult to think this is a documentation bug when it clearly says "There is a distinction between Abort and abort". It is almost like "Note: this is not a documentation bug, we really meant it". On the other hand, yes, it is the first time when I hear of case sensitivity in Delphi. I would call this one of the biggest bugs in Embarcadero's documentation since it is so distinctly highlighted.

Comment: @TomBrunberg - nope, not even by FAR a duplicate. The documentation I link to CLEARLY says that there is a difference between Abort and abort. So, the question seems to boil down to a massive documentation error instead of a problem about Delphi being case sensitive.

Comment: just for statistics and fun:   https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Case-sensitivity_of_identifiers

Answer (score 4):

I just checked in C++ builder and "abort" takes you to stdlib.h while "Abort" takes you to Syste.SysUtils.hpp.

So, yes, that prominent notice seems to apply to C++ not to Delphi. 
But then, why they haven't wrote `abort()` instead of `abort` and `Abort()` instead of `Abort'?

It must have been a sloppy Monday for the documentation guy. The Delphi demo code put in that page (but no C++ code) and the fact that if you uncheck the "show only C++ documentation" checkbox does not remove the notice, adds to the confusion.

Comment: Why bother. Some bugs are there since... ever (as you show). Embarcadero clearly does not intend to already known bugs, so why reporting even more? Plus, now we have to pay for those bug fixes. I really agree for paying for features, but for bugs and bug fixes..... nope. I really hope one day Lazarus will raise and shine!